# mutt-1.7.0: how to display Thunderbird labels / keywords / tags?

Tags: thunderbird, imap, mutt, dovecot

I am aware that standardized e-mail labels, keywords, tags is a mess. But here goes anyway.

Gentoo `mutt` comes with https://www.neomutt.org/feature/keywords patch.

My IMAP server is `dovecot-2.2`.

`:set index_format = ... %Y ...` works for label names stored directly in relevant headers, but for IMAP, protocol-specific keywords are used for storage (http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir) and these are not showing up.

`mutt` doesn't seem to be able to get to them, even with the `feature/keywords` patch. Am I misconfiguring or missing something?